# Hard drive speed normal on some sessions while slow on other sessions

Tags: linux, hard-drive, unix, hardware-failure

I'm currently running Slackware 13 on my Dell D600 and until recently, everything was functioning normally.

What I've been noticing more lately is when I turn my computer on after its been off for at least an hour, the hard drive runs at a slow speed yet all the booting procedure goes well. So I did a normal linux shutdown then turned my computer back on and let it boot. After doing this a few times I noticed the hard drive is running at its normal speed again.

But the problem is if I turn my computer off, wait an hour and turn the computer back on again, then the problem returns.

Is there some setting in unix I can use to overcome this issue? or is some other hardware in my computer now electrically broken?

**An idea**

I have an idea which may or may not work.

The hdparm manual states that multiple sectors might be a performance boost but could also mean data corruption. My system sets this value to 16 all the time yet I tried setting it to 0 to disable this feature but when I powered my computer on again, the settings reset to defaults. Could I somehow write these settings directly to the hard drive chips themselves so that they are always applied on reboot regardless of what OS loads on it in the future?

I sound like I need new hard drive firmware but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: "the hard drive runs at a slow speed" – How do you measure this?

Comment: I count the number of seconds it takes for linux to boot from power-on to when its ready for my login. In normal speed mode, its about 1 minute. But when hard drive is slow, its more like 5 minutes booting time.

Comment: Some hard data would be useful. Please [edit] the question and post the two outputs of `hdparm -t -T /dev/sdX`, slow vs. normal. I understand we may need to wait few hours for this.

Comment: Could be a slow disk, or a slow system. Anything in the drive's SMART data? Or is it keeping some low-power mode? Or not set for DMA transfer (see `hdparm`).

Comment: DMA transfer is on, and I ran smartctl. It mentioned about errors that occurred like 3 years ago but since then, no errors. I even ran a short test and still no errors reported.

Comment: I added an idea to my question. If situation gets bad again then I'll post data

Comment: Before trying to tinker with `hdparm` settings, use it to check the settings in both the good and bad case, and compare the two.